# Applying a function to pandas cell and storing multiple returned values in the same row

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm on a mission to hunt down some memory hogs in my script, and having read about the problems with iterrows()/itertuples() I'm currently trying to figure out how to use vectorization to do what is probably quite simple.

The issue boils down to:

A dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1   NaN   NaN
1     2   NaN   NaN
```

A function returning two different values based on a single input:

```
def func(a):
     return a+1,a+5
```

Now I would like to apply this function to each cell in col1 that is equal to 1, and store the result in col2 and col3 of the same row.

At the moment, I'm doing this with a more extended version of this abomination:

```
for row in df.loc[df['col1'] == 1].itertuples():
    a,b = func(df.loc[row.Index, 'col1'])
    df.loc[row.Index,'col2'] = a
    df.loc[row.Index,'col3'] = b
```

Resulting in:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1   2.0   6.0
1     2   NaN   NaN
```

How would you re-write this to be vectorized/performant? Thanks

### Edit

To add some additional context here, func() actually makes network calls based on the data that is passed to it and could fail. Previously I've had a 'continue' statement in my itertuples() loop that skipped to the next row. How could one handle these more complex scenarios in a vectorized version?

Comment: Is this your actual `func` or an example?

Comment: A simplified example

Answer (score 1):

```py
def func(a):
    return a+1,a+5

df['col2'],df['col3'] = np.where(
                                df['col1']==1, # condition
                                func(df['col1']), # if true, do this
                                np.NaN # if false, do this
                                )
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for, but I don't understand it completely yet. Here all of `df['col1']` is being passed to `func()`, and not row per row as I imagined. How does func() handle the entire col? Can you explain how that works?

Comment: I'd be lieing if I said I completely understand, but I believe that it is that `np.where()` itself is doing the work to make sure that `func()` gets just the single value. That is, `np.where()` returns an array/series/column, and that means each row in it will need to be calculated. So that function handles doing the calculation by-row. If you were to replace the second parameter in `np.where()` with just `df['col1'] + 1` you would get a return that is a column where you've added one on each row. it'll do the same sorta think with our `func()`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df['col2']=df.where(data["col1"]==1)["col1"].apply(lambda x:func(x)[0])
df['col3']=df.where(data["col1"]==1)["col1"].apply(lambda x:func(x)[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

for your example you can use apply function, we can add your condition in the function:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0],[2,0,0]],columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
def funct(a):
  if a==1:
     return(a+1,a+5)
df[['col2','col3']]=df.col1.apply(funct).tolist()
```

Comment: everything I've seen/heard has said that `.apply()` is not vectorized and not very performant. Not that it has no use or anything, but OP is specifically asking for the more efficient way to perform the task.